# how to keep old activerecord 2.3 associations.rb in updated rails3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have some inherited code:

I have an Rails 2.3 app that I've updated to Rails 3.1

Main problem:

Inside this code I inherited is a file using these deprecated methods

```
alias_method_chain :association_join, :fix
```

and

```
alias_method_chain :construct_joins, :fix
```

association_join and construct_joins are deprecated and I don't know what should replace them. Does anyone know what I can refactor these to? I can't seem to find any info online at all. Or is there a gem that can fix this deprecation issue?

Inside the app there is a rails 2.3 "fix" file for the associations and it is now failing under the Rails 3.1 update...the general structure of the file is listed below for clarity.

"fix" file

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    module ClassMethods
      class JoinDependency
        class JoinAssociation
          def association_join_with_fix
          ...
          end
          alias_method_chain :association_join, :fix
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyThroughAssociation
      def construct_joins_with_fix(custom_joins = nil)
      ...
      end
      alias_method_chain :construct_joins, :fix
    end
  end
end
```

.
.
.

Entire file listed below for the interested...

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    module ClassMethods
      class JoinDependency
        class JoinAssociation
          def association_join_with_fix
            connection = reflection.active_record.connection
            join = case reflection.macro
                   when :has_and_belongs_to_many
                     " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                                                             table_alias_for(options[:join_table], aliased_join_table_name),
                                                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                             options[:foreign_key] || reflection.active_record.to_s.foreign_key,
                                                             connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                                                             reflection.active_record.primary_key] +
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                                                               table_name_and_alias,
                                                               connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                               klass.primary_key,
                                                               connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                               options[:association_foreign_key] || klass.to_s.foreign_key
                                                              ]
                   when :has_many, :has_one
                     case
                     when reflection.options[:through]
                       through_conditions = through_reflection.options[:conditions] ? "AND #{interpolate_sql(sanitize_sql(through_reflection.options[:conditions]))}" : ''

                       jt_foreign_key = jt_as_extra = jt_source_extra = jt_sti_extra = nil
                       first_key = second_key = as_extra = nil

                       if through_reflection.options[:as] # has_many :through against a polymorphic join
                         jt_foreign_key = through_reflection.options[:as].to_s + '_id'
                         jt_as_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                            connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                            connection.quote_column_name(through_reflection.options[:as].to_s + '_type'),
                                                            klass.quote_value(parent.active_record.base_class.name)
                                                           ]
                       else
                         jt_foreign_key = through_reflection.primary_key_name
                       end

                       case source_reflection.macro
                       when :has_many
                         if source_reflection.options[:as]
                           first_key   = "#{source_reflection.options[:as]}_id"
                           second_key  = options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
                           as_extra    = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                              connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                              connection.quote_column_name("#{source_reflection.options[:as]}_type"),
                                                              klass.quote_value(source_reflection.active_record.base_class.name)
                                                             ]
                         else
                           first_key   = source_reflection.association_foreign_key # through_reflection.klass.base_class.to_s.foreign_key
                           second_key  = source_reflection.primary_key_name # options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
                         end

                         unless through_reflection.klass.descends_from_active_record?
                           jt_sti_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                               connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                               connection.quote_column_name(through_reflection.active_record.inheritance_column),
                                                               through_reflection.klass.quote_value(through_reflection.klass.sti_name)]
                         end
                       when :belongs_to
                         first_key = primary_key
                         if reflection.options[:source_type]
                           second_key = source_reflection.association_foreign_key
                           jt_source_extra = " AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                                  connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                                  connection.quote_column_name(reflection.source_reflection.options[:foreign_type]),
                                                                  klass.quote_value(reflection.options[:source_type])
                                                                 ]
                         else
                           second_key = source_reflection.primary_key_name
                         end
                       end

                       " #{join_type} %s ON (%s.%s = %s.%s%s%s%s) " % [
                                                                       table_alias_for(through_reflection.klass.table_name, aliased_join_table_name),
                                                                       connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                                       connection.quote_column_name(parent.primary_key),
                                                                       connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                                                                       connection.quote_column_name(jt_foreign_key),
                                                                       jt_as_extra, jt_source_extra, jt_sti_extra
                                                                      ] +
                         " #{join_type} %s ON (%s.%s = %s.%s%s) " % [
                                                                     table_name_and_alias,
                                                                     connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                                     connection.quote_column_name(first_key),
                                                                     connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
                                                                     connection.quote_column_name(second_key),
                                                                     as_extra
                                                                    ]

                     when reflection.options[:as] && [:has_many, :has_one].include?(reflection.macro)
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                                             table_name_and_alias,
                                                                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                                             "#{reflection.options[:as]}_id",
                                                                             connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                                                                             parent.primary_key,
                                                                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                                             "#{reflection.options[:as]}_type",
                                                                             klass.quote_value(parent.active_record.base_class.name)
                                                                            ]
                     else
                       foreign_key = options[:foreign_key] || reflection.active_record.name.foreign_key
                       " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                                                               table_name_and_alias,
                                                               aliased_table_name,
                                                               foreign_key,
                                                               parent.aliased_table_name,
                                                               reflection.options[:primary_key] || parent.primary_key
                                                              ]
                     end
                   when :belongs_to
                     " #{join_type} %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s " % [
                                                             table_name_and_alias,
                                                             connection.quote_table_name(aliased_table_name),
                                                             reflection.klass.primary_key,
                                                             connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
                                                             options[:foreign_key] || reflection.primary_key_name
                                                            ]
                   else
                     ""
                   end || ''
            join << %(AND %s) % [
                                 klass.send(:type_condition, aliased_table_name)] unless klass.descends_from_active_record?

            [through_reflection, reflection].each do |ref|
              join << "AND #{interpolate_sql(sanitize_sql(ref.options[:conditions], aliased_table_name))} " if ref && ref.options[:conditions]
            end

            join
          end
          alias_method_chain :association_join, :fix
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module Associations
    class HasManyThroughAssociation
      def construct_joins_with_fix(custom_joins = nil)
        polymorphic_join = nil
        if @reflection.source_reflection.macro == :belongs_to
          reflection_primary_key = @reflection.klass.primary_key
          source_primary_key     = @reflection.source_reflection.primary_key_name
          if @reflection.options[:source_type]
            polymorphic_join = "AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                   @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name, "#{@reflection.source_reflection.options[:foreign_type]}",
                                                   @owner.class.quote_value(@reflection.options[:source_type])
                                                  ]
          end
        else
          reflection_primary_key = @reflection.source_reflection.primary_key_name
          source_primary_key     = @reflection.source_reflection.association_foreign_key
          if @reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]
            polymorphic_join = "AND %s.%s = %s" % [
                                                   @reflection.quoted_table_name, "#{@reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]}_type",
                                                   @owner.class.quote_value(@reflection.through_reflection.klass.name)
                                                  ]
          end
        end

        "INNER JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s %s #{@reflection.options[:joins]} #{custom_joins}" % [
                                                                                              @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name,
                                                                                              @reflection.quoted_table_name, reflection_primary_key,
                                                                                              @reflection.through_reflection.quoted_table_name, source_primary_key,
                                                                                              polymorphic_join
                                                                                             ]
      end
      alias_method_chain :construct_joins, :fix
    end
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
  module Reflection
    class AssociationReflection
      def association_foreign_key_with_fix
        @association_foreign_key ||= @options[:primary_key] || class_name.foreign_key
      end
      alias_method_chain :association_foreign_key, :fix
    end
  end
end

### EFFECTIVE DIFFERENCE ###
# --- /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/associations.rb.original  2012-02-25 10:58:08.000000000 -0800
# +++ /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/associations.rb   2012-02-25 12:19:49.000000000 -0800
# @@ -2096,8 +2096,8 @@
#                              klass.quote_value(source_reflection.active_record.base_class.name)
#                            ]
#                          else
# -                          first_key   = through_reflection.klass.base_class.to_s.foreign_key
# -                          second_key  = options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
# +                          first_key   = source_reflection.association_foreign_key # through_reflection.klass.base_class.to_s.foreign_key
# +                          second_key  = source_reflection.primary_key_name # options[:foreign_key] || primary_key
#                          end
#
#                          unless through_reflection.klass.descends_from_active_record?
# @@ -2122,9 +2122,9 @@
#
#                        " #{join_type} %s ON (%s.%s = %s.%s%s%s%s) " % [
#                          table_alias_for(through_reflection.klass.table_name, aliased_join_table_name),
# -                        connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
# -                        connection.quote_column_name(parent.primary_key),
#                          connection.quote_table_name(aliased_join_table_name),
# +                        connection.quote_column_name(parent.primary_key),
# +                        connection.quote_table_name(parent.aliased_table_name),
#                          connection.quote_column_name(jt_foreign_key),
#                          jt_as_extra, jt_source_extra, jt_sti_extra
#                        ] +
# --- /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb.original 2012-02-25 10:33:53.000000000 -0800
# +++ /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb  2012-02-25 12:19:56.000000000 -0800
# @@ -160,7 +160,7 @@
#              end
#            else
#              reflection_primary_key = @reflection.source_reflection.primary_key_name
# -            source_primary_key     = @reflection.through_reflection.klass.primary_key
# +            source_primary_key     = @reflection.source_reflection.association_foreign_key
#              if @reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]
#                polymorphic_join = "AND %s.%s = %s" % [
#                  @reflection.quoted_table_name, "#{@reflection.source_reflection.options[:as]}_type",
# --- /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/reflection.rb.original    2012-02-25 10:33:47.000000000 -0800
# +++ /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/active_record/reflection.rb 2012-02-25 12:20:04.000000000 -0800
# @@ -192,7 +192,7 @@
#        end
#
#        def association_foreign_key
# -        @association_foreign_key ||= @options[:association_foreign_key] || class_name.foreign_key
# +        @association_foreign_key ||= @options[:primary_key] || class_name.foreign_key
#        end
#
#        def counter_cache_column
```

Comment: But what is the “fix” actually fixing??

Comment: I honestly do not know. I've updated the question with the entire files contents if that will help

Comment: My advice would be to try just removing this alias as part of the rails upgrade. It was **probably** (??) added as a standalone patch to rails, without actually upgrading the rails version.

Comment: If you'd like to find out exactly what this code is doing, you can try looking at the git history on your project, or even try comparing this version of the code to the corresponding rails version's implementation.